# How can I display the whole text in a cell (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Here's the file I'm using for the table view controller. When I run the project the cell shows the text that's written in "names" but it won't show all of it.

I want it to show the whole text in the same cell. That the cell is sized according to what's written in it.

How do I fix this?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FTBViewController: UITableViewController {

var names = [String]()
var identities = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    names = ["This is the text the cell is displaying but it won't show it all"]
    identities = ["A"]

    self.navigationItem.title = "Guía"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]



}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return names.count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FCell")

    cell?.textLabel!.text = names[indexPath.row]

    return cell!

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(vcName)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add

```
   cell?.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0        
    cell?.textLabel!.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
   cell?.textLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0) // this is optional if you need use this
```

**Full answer**

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FCell")
     cell?.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0        
    cell?.textLabel!.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    cell?.textLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)
    cell?.textLabel!.text = names[indexPath.row]

    return cell!

}
```

Comment: Also consider heightForRowAtIndexPath if your app's deployment target is below 8.0 or if you don't use automatic height for cell. Because you may encounter the same issue even while the above code works fine.

Comment: @Bharath - why, the tableview default height is 43 , it automtically adjust, else we go for calculate the height if it is autoresizing, else use dimesnsion if it is autolayout

Comment: Yes, I just reminded in certain case like if the text gets any lengthier & your deployment target is below 8.0 where auto dimension won't work. In such case you may need to consider heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 2):

You could use following code in *viewdidLoad* :

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Hope so it helps...